# What if I don't send back the remaining satoshis to myself?

Tags: transaction-fees, change

I'm trying to send a tx request to bitcoin node to make a transaction. All tutorials send back the remaining satoshis to themselves. What if I don't do that and don't send remaining satoshis to myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions require that the amount sent in outputs does not exceed the amount consumed by the inputs. The difference between the two is implicitly the transaction's fee, which can be claimed by the miner that accepts the transaction into a block.

Thus, if you construct a transaction which consumes more than you want to send, but don't explicitly add an output to make those coins actually go back to you, you're burning them as transaction fee.

Comment: but i have to give some fees to the miner right? how much is enough if yes?

Comment: Here is the state of the mempool with respect to fees, you must figure out how many bytes your transaction is and include the appropriate fee based on this and your desired speed. https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#BTC,6m,weight